# Math mode in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, sharelatex

This is my first time using LaTeX and I am running into the following issue:

I am trying to denote a set of functions `x_t` which belong to `K` but for some reason the entire sentence gets italicized. I have attached screenshots of my code as well as the compiled result. Can anyone help me fix this? Cheers

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please paste code here rather than a picture of it - preferably in the form of a small but complete document which we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Don't worry, you're not the first and you won't be the last :) It's important to understand that some commands can only appear in math mode, such as `_` and `\mapsto`. This is why LaTeX is inserting the missing `$` signs, but it's put everything in math mode, hence your problems. The next and most important thing to understand is that `$ ... $` shouldn't be used as a way of "mathifying" individual glyphs, or getting special characters, it sets up math mode, which is where the entire equation/relation/expression/object should go, in order to get the right spacing &c.

Answer (score 7):

That code is surely giving you errors when you compile, which will be telling you at least something about the problem. TeX will complain about missing `$` signs and add them in, but it can only guess where to put them.

You want everything from `f_{t}` to `\mathbb{R}`between one set of `$ ... $` and then from `x_{t}` to the end between another set. `f_{t} :` etc. is maths and you have it set as text. Similarly, `\mapsto` etc.

```
$f_{t} \colon \mathcal{K} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$
...
$x_{t} \in \mathcal{K}$
```

**EDIT** Use `\colon` as suggested by Mico.

Comment: That's OK. But if you paste code we can copy-paste, it is a lot easier to help than giving us a screen shot.

Comment: +1. A minor point: Use `\colon` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 4):

`<rant>`
As a regular user of Mathematics.SE, I'm really impressed about the poor quality of TeX/LaTeX input. I acknowledge that some compromise with the limited possibilities offered by MathJax is necessary, but when I see

```
$\rm\ (p-1)!\ mod\ p\:$
```

written by a high rep user, my heart bleeds. Apart from the personal choice of using upright letters everywhere, typing `\mod{p}` shouldn't be too difficult.

One of the most common errors, that I also find in students' typescripts, is believing that `$...$` is just a way to enable special characters. It is not.

Everything which is math *must* be typed in as math, even if it is a standalone variable. In MathJax and, *a fortiori*, in LaTeX.

`</rant>`

So

```
We model our decision set, $\mathcal{K}$, as a convex set
in Euclidean space. Furthermore, we define our convex loss
function as $f_{t}\colon \mathcal{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
At any finite time $t$, we denote our player's decision
as $x_{t} \in \mathcal{K}$.
```

Style manuals say the colon should not be used after "as". Also `\mapsto` is the wrong symbol for functions, it is used to denote a function's action on elements. Also no space should ever precede a comma.

Comment: so, how do you propose getting mathematicians/latex users to read and observe basic introductory material?  (i agree with your rant and have some good examples, but i won't name names since that's politically unwise.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Rejecting badly written manuscripts could be a start. `;-)`

Comment: Er ... who is this rant aimed at? Neither the OP nor I wrote that.

Comment: @cfr Did I say that? I meant to say I've seen much worse code than the OP's.